# Call an automation from Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I was wondering if there is a way to call an automation from the Journey Builder. I'm new to Marketing Cloud and need some help here.

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no standard approach/activity to do so. Standard functionality only allows you to do it the opposite way and trigger a journey from an automation.

However there is the possibility to create custom journey builder activities. Furthermore Marketing Cloud provides APIs that let you interact with automations and also start one immediately. If you combine those two concepts you can create a custom activity that interacts with this API and triggers an automation.
But this requires some coding skills and a server or cloud service to host the custom activity.

**Helpful resources:**

- [SOAP-API documentation - Interact with Automation Studio](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api.htm)
- [Build Custom Activities and Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm)
- [Create a Marketing Cloud App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/create-a-mc-app.htm)
- [Example Code for a custom activity (doesn't fit your use case 100% as it is a split activity)](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit)

Comment: I have an SSJS script that calls an automation, can we invoke this script from journey builder ? Also, can a journey builder perform any query activities like automation (I need to query for a particular field, if it is empty, do a self join on the DE and update that value) ?

Comment: Unfortunately a journey can't perform such an activity - neither SSJS, nor executing query activities. It is possible using a dirty hack, though I cannot really recommend it as it is far from best practice: You could use a email activity and invoke a CloudPage from the exclusion script which triggers your tasks. However, it seems like your process isn't suitable for a journey use case or needs some adaptions. Maybe an Automation is the more suitable way to go?

Comment: @MonikaM If my answer helped you get an overview of the possibilities you have, please mark it as accepted, so others can easily see this has been answered correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the possibilities @Markus Slabina !